# Creating DropDownListFor in a Partial View in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have created a partial view that displays a dropdownlist

`html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectOption, Model.SelectOption)`

I get an error of Object not reference to an instance....

If I put the code above into my view (aspx) it works fine no problem. But in the partial view I get the error.

The textbox controls in my partial view works fine using the same model. I just can't around the DropDownList.

Comment: This code cannot possibly work as the `DropDownListFor` helper expects a lambda expression as first argument whereas you are passing to it a string.

Comment: My mistake copied the wrong code. I've updated the post to avoid confusion.

Comment: What model are you passing to the partial view? Also show how you initialize this model.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You haven't actually shown how you are calling the partial view and whether your controller action has actually passed a model to this view.

Make sure that your controller has properly initialized the model. So if we suppose that you have the following model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string SelectedOption { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SelectOptions { get; set; }
}
```

and the following controller action:

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    var model = new MyViewModel();
    model.SelectOptions = new[]
    {
        new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "item 1" },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "item 2" },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "item 3" },
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

ten you could have a corresponding view which will call a partial:

```
@model MyViewModel
@Html.Partial("_MyPartial", Model)
```

and the `_MyPartial.cshtml`:

```
@model MyViewModel
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedOption, Model.SelectOptionOptions)
```

Notice how you need 2 properties on your view model in order to create a dropdown list => a scalar property (`SelectedOption`) that will be used to bind the selected value and a collection property that will contain the list of values you would like to display in the dropdown (`SelectOptionOptions`).

In your code you are using the same property for both which is wrong:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectOption, Model.SelectOption)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this explanation. It got me half way. I got a populated dropdown by putting the controller action into the Create `ActionResult` (and the `@Html.DropDownListFor` in the Create.cshtml view), which is called when I go into the appropriate URL, but when I created a different `ActionResult` for my partial view, it didn't work and kept giving me an object reference. I'm a bit puzzled...Not sure how to call this partial action to instantiate it properly. Basically, I'm adding a dropdown to the top navbar _Layout.cshtml