# Render two Controller/Views on the same page in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Here's my scenario:

I need to create a page such that I have a view containing a DropDownList, then another (partial?) view beneath it that changes depending on what was selected in the DropDownList. I know how to code the DropDownList and make it work with the controllers, but I'm pretty stumped on how to achieve my goal.

The view that will change based on the DropDown has its own controller with CRUD operations (they contain grids). I should add that i'm using a shared view that contains a sort of template for a grid. There's lots of grids, but one view, and a controller for each grid. So I can't just call in the view as a partial view, as it would have no data. I'm essentially needing to call the controller for each grid, which then renders the view containing the grid.

So how can I do this?

Comment: Partials and ajax are made for this problem.  Look them up.

Comment: Have a look at this example, this is exactly what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8965352/creating-dropdownlistfor-in-a-partial-view-in-mvc let us know if you are stuck somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

you can use partial views to render your views, hence you can use Ajax to update the contents of any element or part of the rendered views dynamically.

you may use jquery to get the selected item value from the drop down list